# Embed a excel object to PPT slide using python

Tags: python, python-pptx

Is there any possibilities to add Excel object in slides of PPT using Python-PPTX?
I have searched many sites for this but none helped me. If there is a way to add excel object to slide please let me know. Thanks in advance.